# Bulk importing Contact Lookup Field

Tags: import, bulk, lookup-field

I have a contact lookup field in Account object.
I have tried to bulk import using data import wizard but is not working. There is no error in the import but the contact lookup field does not update.

In my csv i have:
Account id: salesforce account ID --> to match the account and update it
Contact column: i have tried with the contact ID and contact name

In data import wizard i go to
Update records --> accounts by salesforce ID
and in the contact lookup option i have contact ID but still is not working

Has anyone tried it before? I have around 10k accounts that i need to link a contact and i dont want to do it manually.
I have professional editio so i cant use data loader

hope to hear any suggestions please
thanks